# how to resolve (1045, "Access denied for user 'User'@'IP or host' (using password: YES)") when build django docker container?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, docker

Well, I have multiple databases in django project. One is `default` and second is`test_dev`. i have created docker container. and then everything went well till building the container. after that When I try to call my django app api which is using `test_dev` db for reading data. I have encountered:

```
OperationalError at /api/projects/

(1045, "Access denied for user 'test_dev'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)")
```

In settings file, my **databases configuration:**

```
{
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    "test_dev" : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "test",
        'USER': 'test_dev',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': '?=hosted_domain',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'SSL': True
        }
}
```

If you know any solution. Please help me out of this. Soon I have to put things on production..

Comment: How are you creating the database user?

Comment: database is already created by someone else, I have just credentials to connect..

Comment: please don't post your password, label it as `xxxxx` or something

Comment: @dummyfirst Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1 for similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I solved my problem by changing the engine.
I replaced the following line:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

with :

```
 'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

this code solve my current error but after this i have face an other error that i solve by editing `requirements.txt` file:

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.27
```

to :

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.26
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with database access privileges. Either the password is wrong, the user was not granted permissions to the specific database or table that you need, or the Django container's IP address does not match the one bound to the user.

The following SQL:

1. ensures that the user exists and that login is permitted for that user from any IP address,
2. ensures that the user has all privileges on the database

```sql
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS
  'test_dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
  ON test.*
  TO 'test_dev'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that while creating the database for the container, your user has not get the desired permissions, to give permissions use the below snippet.

In your terminal:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

password is: password (default)

After that, `show databases;` and `use test_dev;`

Now, you can check grants by using `show grants;` command, since the user for all hosts does not have any permissions (or maybe there is no user at all), so use the below command to give privileges:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'test_dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test_dev'@'%';
```